# How do you determine the proper dependency version in a Scala project?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

As soon as I bring in a single dependency (using SBT), I see warnings about multiple dependencies.

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0" % "provided"
)
```

Warnings:

```
       [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
       [warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:(2.10.0, 2.10.4)
       [warn]  * org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:(3.3.2, 3.0)
       [warn]  * org.slf4j:slf4j-api:(1.7.10, 1.7.2)
```

Normally I'm very pedantic about warnings. I want to know why they are there and what I should do to eliminate them. If you let warnings pile up, you quickly have a signal to noise problem.

But how would a novice Scala dev (aka me) know what version to favor?

I'm not really asking how to suppress these warnings, so much as to understand the implications of choosing one version over the other. Seems to me that the source of these warnings is within spark.core, no? How am I to know how to respond?

As soon as I add more dependencies, these warnings pile up and the possibility of a real conflict/problem go up.

I've spent the day trying to find the magic internet search keywords to figure out what to do, but all I'm finding is "how", not "why", if that makes sense.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Based on [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1933) thread, I downgraded from `0.13.8` to `0.13.7`. It did get rid of all the noise, though I'm not sure this is really an "answer". But at least I'm able to add all my dependencies without a boatload of warnings, and now sbt-assembly is working as well.

Answer (score 1):

My reading is that minor versions should be forward compatible, so for slf4j it shouldn't matter. The same with the Scala version, moving from 2.10.0 to 2.10.4 shouldn't be a problem (Scala guarantees binary compatibility between minor versions). The only thing that might be a problem here is Apache Commons.

You can use the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin to find out more precisely which libraries depend on which versions. Also I think if you run `sbt evicted` you get more information about conflicting versions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into sbt-dependency-graph. I've run sbt evicted, but the results didn't help me determine if I had a problem or not. I just find it odd that bringing in a single dependency should result in warnings -- why wouldn't those be resolved in the spark-core library itself?

Comment: @Stuart - I tried your example and did not get any warning although Spark seems to depend on roughly one hundred libraries. Which sbt version are you specifying? I'm putting `sbt.version=0.13.11` (latest) into `project/build.properties`.

Comment: We were using 0.13.8, but changed to 0.13.7 (see the update in OP)